# Input field extends after setting value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my app I have few forms where users can pick the value and that value will show in text input field. These values are usually one to three characters. Once I pick the value my input field extends (changed the width). Input field has enough space (size set to 10) and there is no reason to be extended. I have checked if my values are trimmed and nothing is odd with the value. I'm wondering if this is related to JQuery .val() that I use or something else? Here is example of my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="formItem">
    <label for="status">Status:</label>
    <input type="text" name="status" id="status" value="" data-master="SS_STATUS" size="10" maxlength="10" readonly />
    <img src="Images/add.png" alt="Click to add value" class="masterRecords" />
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
//Looping through the table with the records where users choose desired code/value for their input field
$('#searchTbl tbody tr').on('click', function(){
    var codeVal = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text()); //Here I grab the value from the table
    $('#status').val(codeVal).css('font-weight','bold'); //Here input field is populated
});
```

I have attached image where you can see input field before and after user selects the value. There is obvious difference in field size. Nothing changed in HTML structure (I monitored in my dev tools after value is set).

[image: Input Field]

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or code snippet? There's something else going on the we can't see - have you checked `var codeVal` is indeed just a number? As you're returning .`text()` it could be anything

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, you're not only setting a value, but also applying a style: `.css('font-weight','bold');`, I suspect it's the reason you have a change of your input's width...

Try removing this call to `.css()` to check, and if it confirms, try applying your style once on rendering the page...

Comment: I have removed css and that fixed the problem. Still I can't see the reason why that would affect size of the input field?

Comment: I'd say an input's real width is computed based on its number of chars, and a char's witdh depends on the boldness of the char...